# How can I check if every textbox in my form isn't null?

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, textbox

```
If dblRoundTrip > 0 And dblRoundTrip < 100 Then
    If dblDaysWorked > 0 And dblDaysWorked < 32 Then
        If dblPerGallon > 0 And dblPerGallon < 50 Then
            If dblGasCost > 0 And dblGasCost < 5 Then
                If dblMaint > 0 And dblMaint < 500 Then
                    If dblParking > 0 and dblParking < 500 Then
                        If dblInsure > 0 And dblInsure < 500 Then
                            blnValidateCheck = True
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If
```

I have to check all these TextBoxes to be a certain number, but my main concern is if they actually have something in them. I don't want another cluster of if statements to check for null TextBoxes. I was thinking a loop statement would be best, but I don't know how to work that around.

Comment: Null textboxes or null/empty strings? You should check first if the texts can be parsed to double. Use `Double.TryParse`.

Comment: Those look like they are all double vars.  Where do textboxes come into play.  Are they the source?  Also those need not be nested like that.  You could accumulate errors by testing each case individually.

Comment: A note: `TextBox.Text` will never be `NULL` it would be an empty `String`...

Comment: You cold also use a NumericUpDown and avoid all the issues -  each could be set to those ranges, would be a value so it could never be an empty string and never need to be parsed

Answer (score 0):

You should  first check if the texts can be parsed to double. Use `Double.TryParse`. You should also avoid to nest `If`-statements.

```
Dim blnValidateCheck As Boolean = False
blnValidateCheck = Double.TryParse(TxtRoundTrip.Text, dblRoundTrip) _
                   AndAlso dblRoundTrip > 0 AndAlso dblRoundTrip < 100
If blnValidateCheck Then
    blnValidateCheck = Double.TryParse(TxtDaysWorked.Text, dblDaysWorked) _
                       AndAlso dblDaysWorked > 0 AndAlso dblDaysWorked < 32
End If
If blnValidateCheck Then
    blnValidateCheck = Double.TryParse(TxtPerGallon.Text, dblPerGallon) _
                       AndAlso dblPerGallon > 0 AndAlso dblPerGallon < 50
End If
' ....
```

This is much more readable, testable and maintainable.

Another safe approach is to use a [`NumericUpDown`-control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown(v=vs.110).aspx) which supports ranges.

Answer (score 0):

> **my main concern is if they actually have something in them**

Here is a `Linq` solution... (Checks if any `TextBox` control on the `Form` has a valid `Double` in them). Also I did not address the check for comparison as that was not your concern...

```
Public Shared Function TextBoxControlsEmpty(ByVal frm As Form) As Boolean
    Return Not frm.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)().All(Function(t) Double.TryParse(t.Text, New Double))
End Function
```

**Usage**

```
 If TextBoxControlsEmpty(Me) Then
    'Handle this...
 Else
    'None are empty and are doubles...
 End If
```